# How to recursively get access to object values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, recursion

I have an array with recursive objects which looks like this:

```
export const a: A = [
    {
        person: [
            {
                person: [{
                    person: [],
                    rating: 512,
                    justNumbers: [30, 15, 327]
                },
                    {
                        person: [
                            {
                                person: [],
                                rating: 538,
                                justNumbers: [13, 55, 643]
                            },
                            {
                                person: [],
                                rating: 964,
                                justNumbers: [314, 523, 512]
                            }
                        ],
                        rating: 413,
                        justNumbers: [876, 541, 623]
                    }],
                rating: 176,
                justNumbers: [842, 812,643]
            }
        ],
        rating: 235,
        justNumbers: [33, 565, 73]
    }];
```

I need to create a function to sum all ratings in recursive way and to create an array of numbers from all numbers in every justNumbers array, which is sorted in ascending order.

```
  const recursiveNumbersSearch = (obj: object, targetKey: string, getSum = []) => {
    const r = getSum;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        const value: any = obj[key];
        if (key === targetKey && typeof value !== 'object') {
            r.push(value)
        } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
            recursiveNumbersSearch(value, targetKey, r);
        }
    })
    return getSum
}

function sumArray (arr : number[]): number {
    let arraySum: number = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i<= arr.length - 1; i++) {
        arraySum = arr[i] + arraySum;
    }
    return arraySum;
}
```

I did this and it counts the sum pretty well, however, there are few compiler errors which are:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

First one goes for string:

```
const value: any = obj[key];
```

When second one refers to:

```
r.push(value)
```

I am a little bit confused, because if I run compiled JS file with node it properly counts the sum, however it does point at those two errors.

From the other hand I am unable to push arrays of justNumbers using the recursiveNumberSearch method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you're having problems with the arrays is because you test `typeof value === 'object'`, but that will be true if `value` in an Array.

Here, I write what I think is a simpler version of `recursiveNumbersSearch`, called `deepProp`.  It takes a property name and returns a function that takes an object and does a depth-first traversal, retrieving the named property wherever it's found. We can then use that to layer on simple functions to sum the `rating` properties or
flatten and sort the `justNumbers` ones, like this:

```js
const deepProp = (prop) => ({[prop]: p, ...rest}) =>
  p == undefined
    ? Object .values (rest) .flatMap (deepProp (prop))
    : [p, ... deepProp (prop) (rest)]

const a = [{person: [{person: [{person: [], rating: 512, justNumbers: [30, 15, 327]}, {person: [{person: [], rating: 538, justNumbers: [13, 55, 643]}, {person: [], rating: 964, justNumbers: [314, 523, 512]}], rating: 413, justNumbers: [876, 541, 623]}], rating: 176, justNumbers: [842, 812, 643]}], rating: 235, justNumbers: [33, 565, 73]}]

console .log (deepProp ('rating') (a))
console .log (deepProp ('justNumbers') (a))

const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const sumRatings = (o) => sum (deepProp ('rating') (o))
const organizeNumbers = (o) => deepProp ('justNumbers') (o) .flat () .sort ((a, b) => a - b)

console .log (sumRatings (a))
console .log (organizeNumbers (a))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I'm afraid I have nothing to offer for your Typescript errors.